# How to dump as XML programmatically generated Layout

Tags: android, xml, view

Is there any possible method to dump programmatically generated Layout?

For example I create Layout

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this.mContext);

//...some code here

mainLayout.addView(picker);
mainLayout.addView(mOldColor);
mainLayout.addView(separator);
mainLayout.addView(mNewColor);
```

Now how to dump to Lod.d for example and get XML representation of Layout with attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Afraid not.  Views themselves know nothing about the xml they came from, so there's no way to force them to serialize back to xml.

Now if you wanted to do it on your own you can walk a view hierarchy fairly easily.  But since views don't turn in to xml, you'd have to query each property individually and build the xml by hand.  And it wouldn't work at all for custom views that could have custom attributes.  And you'd have to use reflection to get the class name for the view type in the xml.  Basically a lot of work for something fairly fragile.